# SQL Server Management Studio Display Database Diagrams (ER) Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I was wondering if anybody knew exactly what permissions where needed on a database in SQL Server 2005+ so that when a person uses SQL Server Management Studio, they could then be able to at minimum see the Database Diagrams.

I have tried giving the person db_datareader, db_datawriter, and db_ddladmin, but to no avail.

I have also tried giving them access in the Properties → Effective Permissions of the user.  Under Effective Permissions, I could not find the database object type for "database diagrams" or anything like that to give the user access to.

They are running SQL Server Management Studio (non-express version.)

Any help would be great.

FYI, I did not want to give them db_owner access.

EDIT:

1. As to one of the comments: Yes, the database is an SQL Server 2005 database.
2. As to one of the answers, moving the DB from production to development is not an option.

Comment: Is the database they are working with a 2005 database? (just checking)

Comment: For anyone coming here via Google in 2019: [As of SSMS 18, Database Diagrams are deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#deprecated-features).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Giving admin rights is not the right approach, you need to be Database Owner for Database Diagrams, [check out this thread for more details](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/8715f383-3e28-4910-93f9-5cca51d48380/).

Comment: I'm the DB owner but I can't see the `Diagram` folder, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

First you need to set up Diagram Designer (you need to be db_owner for that). Just expand the Diagrams node, and press 'Yes' to enable diagramming.

After that all other db users can create diagrams and see **their own** diagrams. Only db_owner can see other's diagrams.

Also the db_owner can change diagram owner to himself, but the original owner must be removed from database before doing that.

Answer (score -5):

Copy the database to a development system, and grant the developers administrative rights. Anything else is a waste of time (like researching this question.)

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701214/should-developers-have-administrator-permissions-on-their-pc) for better explanations.

Comment: What's the point in saying that researching this question is a 'waste of time'?