# Missing Database Diagrams node for SQL Azure database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio SSMS 2012?

Tags: sql-server, azure

When connecting to a windows azure SQL server database from SQL server management studio, the database diagrams node appears to be missing.

See attached image. I installed from 'en_sql_server_2012_enterprise_edition_x86_x64_dvd_813294' but can't find the option.

[image]

Maybe my DBA needs to enable diagramming? Per [SQL Server Management Studio Display Database Diagrams (ER) Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849784/sql-server-management-studio-display-database-diagrams-er-permissions?rq=1)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you connecting to? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: I believe it is a 2008 R2 database.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't connecting to SQL Azure? The Federations node makes it seem (to me at least) that this is SQL Azure and not 2008 R2.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I forgot we were on Azure. That would explain why Redgate's Dependency Tracker tool couldn't see objects...

Comment: Tim, if you could make an answer below with that answer, I will mark it as the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be SQL Azure and not SQL Server 2008 R2 (based on the presence of the Federations node in the supplied screenshot). Right now, your best bet to diagram the database is to create the database locally on SQL Server and generate the diagram from there. Hopefully the tooling catches up for SQL Azure soon!

Answer (score 4):

Since July 2015 there has been a preview version of SSMS where the Management Explorer has allowed database diagrams on Azure, it works great so the tooling has almost finally caught up.

Search for "SQL Server Management Studio preview".  Currently the April 2016 preview can be downloaded here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx